# How do I compile the hello world program for Arduino ADK?

Tags: android, arduino, adk

All I'm trying to do is compile the Arduino to Android 'hello world' program from the book "Beginning Android ADK with Arduino".

Here is the code

```
#include <Max3421e.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

AndroidAccessory acc("Manufacturer", "Model", "Description",
                     "Version", "URI", "Serial");

char hello[ARRAY_SIZE] = {'h','e','l','l','o',' ',
                          'w','o','r','l','d','!'};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  acc.powerOn();
}

void loop() {
  if (acc.isConnected()) {
    for(int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++) {
      Serial.print(hello[x]);
      delay(250);
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(250);
  }
}
```

And my error

```
C:\Users\efossum\arduino-1.0.1\libraries\UsbHost/AndroidAccessory.h: In function 'void setup()':
C:\Users\efossum\arduino-1.0.1\libraries\UsbHost/AndroidAccessory.h:68: error: 'void AndroidAccessory::powerOn()' is private
sketch_aug23a:14: error: within this context
```

I looked in AndroidAccessory.h and sure enough it is private, but what should I change to make this work? I assume making the function pulic is not the answer.

Comment: Hi Eric. Did you manage to compile the code? I tried compiling on IDE v22 and v1.0.2 using the library from step 1 over arduino labs website  http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/AccessoryMode .I tried on windows 8 and ubuntu 12.10 with the same error like you. This is really frustrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! I just made the visibility of the `read()` function in the `<AndroidAccessory.h>` header public and used `begin()` instead of `powerOn()` like Mickaël said, and now the code compiles successful.

Comment: What is the difference between begin and poweron?

Comment: @Eric Fossum - In the AndroidAccessory.cpp of the newest library, I see the powerOn() was added to change the return type from void to boolean(true). I don't see why this was neccessary other than to break backwards compatibility.

Comment: Another thing to mention is that after I compiled the code, I used the code for the android part from this blog http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/ and although it worked a year ago for me, it does not work anymore on the Xperia Play running android 2.3.4. I am having a hard time reading the exceptions thrown because the phone is connected to the arduino and not to the PC-eclipse

Comment: You should use TCP/IP debugging when connected to the Arduino, but maybe your Xperia 2.3.4 never incorporated the whole ADK. It was not necessary for manufacturers until after 2.3.4

Comment: And adding a return value to a function won't reduce backwards compatibility, but removing it would.

Comment: Today I succeeded communicating with the Arduino ADK and Xperia Play. Yet now there seem to be another problem. I am sending some values in a byte[] buffer from the phone and receiving totally different values in the ADK board.... Must investigate further. How are you doing with your project?

Comment: I chose to accept your answer because it was more in depth than the one you used. My project has hit a wall haha I started doing other stuff, but maybe I should get back to it. What are you making?

Comment: I made a remote controlled car over WiFi using 2 phones and an ADK. I am now struggling with the video streamming feature .. AAARRGGGGHH.. ANDROOOOID

Comment: Sounds cool. Well hey, if you wanna discuss more my email is in my profile.

Answer (score 3):

It seems:

```
  acc.powerOn()
```

can be replaced with:

```
  acc.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Arduino 0.22 or 0.23 IDE

Comment: It says 1.0.1, how do I tell which 0.xx number it is?

Comment: Although I cannot prove that this is the answer, I have the same code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could also be that the wrong board was chosen during compile. If you choose the wrong board the Arduino software cannot decide which chip or pins you have.